# Save file content after getting data from function and then writing in a text file

Tags: python

I am writing a script that takes input from user and store it to the text file.. It is working fine but each time i run the script, my text file gets overwrite.
Is there any way to save the data permanently and it will not be overwritten.

```
class reports:
    def __init__(self):      

        self.BrandDetails= "Give details for Brands"
        self.UserDetails = "Give details for Users"


    def brands(self,bname,bid):
        name=bname
        id=bid
        print("\t")
        print "Brand name is ", name
        print "Brand Id is", id
##        return name, id

        fp = open("test.txt","w")
        fp.seek(6,2)
        fp.write('\t')
        fp.write('bname: %s, id: %s' % (bname or '', bid or ''))
        fp.close()

        print "\nFile data is: \t \n"
        f=open('test.txt',"r+")
        print f.read()




brand= reports()
print brand.BrandDetails

brand.brands(raw_input("Enter Brand name:"),
        input("Enter Brand Id: "))


class users(reports):


    def userdetails(self,uname,uid):
            name=uname
            id=uid
            print("\t")
            print "User name is ", name
            print "User Id is", id

            fp = open("test.txt","r+")
            fp.seek(6,2)
            fp.write('')
            fp.write('uname: %s, uid: %s' % (uname or '', uid or ''))
            fp.close()

            print "\nFile data is: \t \n"
            f=open('test.txt',"r+")
            print f.read()



u=users()
print "\n\n"
print u.UserDetails

u.userdetails(raw_input("Enter User name:"),
        input("Enter User Id: "))
```

I am novice to python. so, I am asking such question

Comment: What do you mean by "details from a function"? Can you give examples of what details from a function you'd like to save?

Comment: like I want to save brand name and Id from brands() Function to a text file

Comment: You already know how to create and save to a file, so what's the problem then? Perhaps you don't know how to *return* data from a function?

Comment: Just as a minor nitpick: please stay consistent with your "print" calls and use parentheses for all of them. You should use Python 3 anyway, if you are not obliged to maintain some 2.x project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
#File :  /tmp/test.py

class reports:
    def __init__(self):
        self.BrandDetails= "Give details for Brands"
        self.UserDetails = "Give details for Users"

    def brands(self, bname, bid):
        name=bname
        id=bid
        fp = open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w')
        fp.write('\t')
        fp.write('bname: %s, id: %s' % (bname or '', bid or ''))
        fp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    brand= reports()
    print brand.BrandDetails

    brand.brands(raw_input("Enter Brand name:"),
                    input("Enter Brand Id: "))
```

**Output :**

```
python /tmp/test.py
Give details for Brands
Enter Brand name:Nile
Enter Brand Id: 123
[~]$ cat /tmp/test.txt
        bname: Nile, id: 123
```

Comment: Surely it would be better to `return` a value from a function and then one could both write to the text file or store the data in a variable if they so wished.

Comment: Yes, if user want to perform write in single, file then he can use `return` and `write` to file at one place. Let the questioner give choice :)

Comment: it is giving an error "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'"

Comment: You might be not passing value to `bname` and `bid`. Please check `bname` and `bid` value.

Comment: I added file and output. Please check, if its working in mine then it must work in your setup.

Comment: @Lafada Could you stop suggesting bad tag-wiki please? If you want to get the Research Assistant badge, this is definitely not the way to do. Wiki-tag are not a dummy copy/paste from what you can find on internet. So please, stop that.